# CSS single property classes

Tags: css

As more presentational html properties get deprecated the natural response for me was to make single property CSS classes such as .text-align-left{text-align:left}. My question is, is this preferred versus inline styles?

Stackoverflow actually uses quite a bit of inline styles.

PS: I know this isn't really a coding question and it is likely to incite debate but stackoverflow is the largest stack exchange for code and this question does have some use for future individuals.

Comment: It indeed “is likely to incite debate” rather that lead to answers that can be objectively judged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regardless of the reasons why inline styling is used or not on stackoverflow.com, it is in general a bad practice as it makes maintenance a pain.

however single property, utility classes like the one you have mentioned, are quite verbose.

Answer (score 0):

It's good coding to separate the the visual (CSS) and content (HTML) so definitely single properties are better choice.

Comment: this is not totally correct. separation of presentation and content is more about not using markup (HTML) for presentation purposes; e.g. table layouts, `<strong>` tags for bold etc

Comment: @Luca Wait what do you use in place of strong tags then?

Comment: @Luca's answer that's exactly what I was thinking, I'll wait a bit longer for more responses before accepting a answer.

Comment: @user1490379 this should be another question really :) but anyway: `<strong>` tags should be semantically used to mark strong emphasis. `<b>` tags can be used to visually display some copy as bold - without any semantic meaning. `font-weight: bold` is the css way of achieving bold text, again without any semantic meaning.

Comment: Lol brain fart totally forgot to use b tags